# Spring mongo repository sort descending by a certain property

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I want to sort Descending by lastChange property, the List of items from mongo.

**RequestRepository interface:**

```
public interface RequestRepository extends MongoRepository<Request, String> {
    List<Request> findByUser(String id);
}
```

Request.java:

```
@Document(collection = "Requests")
public class Request {

@Id
private String id;
private String user;
private String username;
private String requestTitle;
private String requestMessage;
private boolean read;
private Date lastChange;
private Date requestDate;
private boolean isActiveRequest;
private boolean isPremiumRequest; //paid request

public Request() {}

public Request(
        String user,
        String requestTitle,
        String requestMessage,
        boolean read,
        Date lastChange,
        Date requestDate,
        boolean isActiveRequest) {
    this.user = user;
    this.requestTitle = requestTitle;
    this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
    this.read = read;
    this.lastChange = lastChange;
    this.requestDate = requestDate;
    this.isActiveRequest = isActiveRequest;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getRequestTitle() {
    return requestTitle;
}

public void setRequestTitle(String requestTitle) {
    this.requestTitle = requestTitle;
}

public String getRequestMessage() {
    return requestMessage;
}

public void setRequestMessage(String requestMessage) {
    this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
}

public boolean isRead() {
    return read;
}

public void setRead(boolean read) {
    this.read = read;
}

public Date getLastChange() {
    return lastChange;
}

public void setLastChange(Date lastChange) {
    this.lastChange = lastChange;
}

public Date getRequestDate() {
    return requestDate;
}

public void setRequestDate(Date requestDate) {
    this.requestDate = requestDate;
}

public boolean isActiveRequest() {
    return isActiveRequest;
}

public void setActiveRequest(boolean activeRequest) {
    isActiveRequest = activeRequest;
}

public boolean isPremiumRequest() {
    return isPremiumRequest;
}

public void setPremiumRequest(boolean premiumRequest) {
    isPremiumRequest = premiumRequest;
}
}
```

In my code I have the following list:

```
List<Request> = RequestRepository.findByUser(userObj.getId());
```

I want to have the data from `RequestRepository.findByUser(userObj.getId());` sorted DESCENDING by the property `lastChange`.

I have searched on StackOverflow, and found the following method to sort:

```
List<Request> findAllByOrderByUpdatedAtDesc();
```

but this does not work if I search by User.

What is the solution to search by User id and to sort by `lastChange`?

Thank you!

Comment: Show Your Request class, how it looks

Comment: It's a simple model. I will update the code

Comment: where is created_at field in your model?

Comment: it is named lastChange, I have edited the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it.

```
List<Request> findByUserOrderByLastChangeDesc(String user);
```

Update your question with proper details.

Comment: I had tried similar thing, but instead of And I was using By, I will try it now

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped to solve the question!